# UICollectionView is scrolling when selecting a cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm having trouble when i try to select an item inside a `UICollectionView` since when I click on it it scrolls a little bit.

I know `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` is being called but I want to prevent the scrolling when selecting. I only want the collection view to scroll when the user is scrolling through but if the user is just tapping the cell it shouldn't move. Only should be selected.

I hope you can help me since I don't know how to prevent this problem.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: This is also happening when using list layout in collectionView using functionally equivalent code to what would be done in a UITableView.

Answer (score 106):

If you are selecting the cell programmatically with `collectionview.selectItem(at: indexpath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .top)` -- and since you didn't share any of your code with us, let's assume that's correct...

... then like me you might not have realized that you can use an empty set like this: `collectionview.selectItem(at: indexpath, animated: true, scrollPosition: [])`

Comment: That is diabolical, since when were `[.foo]` and `.foo` equivalent ways to specify an `OptionSet`?!

Answer (score 12):

This can happen if you have paging enabled and the CollectionView is manually scrolled to a position that doesn't align with the expected page boundaries.  When you select the cell, it adjusts to put the CollectionView at the correct page boundaries.

Comment: Hi @CodeSmith, this helped me 2 years later but I do want to keep the paging behavior on my scrollView. Did you manage to get the best of both?

Comment: I think my fix was to implement a custom UICollectionViewLayout and get the page size to fit correctly on the screen.  The pages were a few pixels off and the layout fixed the sizing issues.

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 5 you can do

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 10, section: 0)

self.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
```

in `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
collectionView.selectItem(at: newIdexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition(rawValue: 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I solved the issue by defining a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

```
    private var flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5)
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionView.ScrollDirection.horizontal
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 15
        return flowLayout
    }
```

and assigning it to the collectionView

```
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
```

Answer (score -3):

swift 5

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)

}
```