# Why does my UICollectionView scroll up when clicking on a cell?

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview, uiedgeinsets

My `UICollectionView` always scrolls a bit up when clicking on a `UICollectionViewCell`. 
I noticed that this behavior does not occur if I set the collection view inset to 0 (no inset at all) and the `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` to `.never`.

However, I still want to have a content inset (of 8px on bottom and top) on my `UICollectionView` without that automated scrolling. I am not sure why this behavior occurs and what exactly it has to do with the content inset property.

Is there a way to have a custom inset that does not lead to scrolling whenever a `UICollectionViewCell` is tapped?

This is my configuration within `viewDidLoad()`:

```
self.collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 8, right: 0)
// self.collectionView?.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
// When setting the contentInset to zero and the contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior to never, it does not scroll
```

The VC looks like this:

[image]

Every cell represents a message. The view at the bottom is an `inputAccessoryView`.

The behavior does not occur when I remove the `inputAccessoryView`.
This might also be related to this discussion: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18424

Comment: What code do you have in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` function?

Comment: Nothing @Jake. I just have a custom `inputAccessoryView` that is placed on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Do you have your constraints set?

Comment: For the inputAccessoryView? I did. I added an image to my answer to make clear how my view controller looks like. @Jake This might also be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081218/uicollectionview-is-scrolling-when-selecting-a-cell. However, I don't select cells programmatically here.

Comment: I think that you may be experiencing a constraints issue between the two views. Do you know how to use the Debug View Hierarchy ? I would analyze the views and margins before and after a cell click using that tool to see what is occurring.

Comment: I am not that experienced using it..but I will find it out. Are you talking about the constraints between the `inputAccessoryView` and the `collectionView`?

Comment: Yes. Something may be acting in an unexpected way

Comment: Does not seem to be the case, as I didn't even set constraints on the `inputAccessoryView`
, I just set its frame. The `inputAccessoryView` is not even visible in the View Hierarchy Debugger.

Comment: Try setting a constraint on the collection view's bottom margin to the top of the inputAccessoryView

Comment: That doesn't work because the `inputAccessoryView` is not added within `viewDidLoad()` but by overriding the `inputAccessoryView` property.

Comment: Access the height of the `inputAccessoryView` and set the bottom constraint of the `CollectionView` to the bottom of the view offset by the height of the `inputAccessoryView` That should solve your problem.

Comment: @Jake Woohoo! I really spent way too much time and effort in solving this minor issue! I'd hug you if I could. Unfortunately, I couldn't change the Autolayout constraints of the `UICollectionView`, but I could change its frame (more precisely, its height) and decrease it by the height of the `inputAccessoryView`. That works like a charm. Awesome. If you'd like to answer this question; I'd accept your answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks @T.Meyer happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Answer - Read the comments

My suspicion was layout issues. To correct the issue the layout needs to be statically set, that way it doesn't adjust when it's interacted with. That could usually be done with constraints, in this circumstance setting the height of the `CollectionView` offset by the `inputAccessoryView` was the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it happens with on collection view when you have *paging enabled* selected. Just deselect **paging enabled** and it should be alright.

[image: See attached image]

Comment: This solution solved my case. I forgot to disable paging after handling it myself.